# facebook share box nothing show in dialog

Tags: php, facebook

this is dialog box when i click on share button then show empty nothing show any thing text summery and image when i first time test it  working perfectly every thing show and share on facebook after 5 to 6 hours letter it not working  below is my code

[image]

this is meta data  i am shere on face book

```
<meta property="og:url"                content="<?php echo  $gurl; ?>" />
<meta property="og:type"               content="article" />
<meta property="og:title"              content="<?php echo str_replace('-',' ',url_title($results[0]['QTitle'])) ;?>" />
<meta property="og:description"        content="<?php echo substr($results[0]['QDesc'],0,300); ?>" /> 
<meta property="og:image:width" content="225"/>
<meta property="og:image:height" content="225"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo base_url('assets/images/question.jpg');?>"/>
```

this is click button share ha metiral on facebook

```
   <a onClick="window.open('http://www.fac

    ebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&amp;p[title]=<?php echo urlencode($title);?>&amp;p[url]=<?php echo urlencode($gurl1); ?>&amp;&p[images][0]=<?php echo urlencode(base_url('assets/images/question.jpg'));?>','sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=548,height=325');" href="javascript: void(0)"> 
                                                     <img height="30px;" src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/images/pop_facebook.png" alt="Facebook" />
                                                 </a>
```

please help me i try to find the error  but helpless

Comment: The Share dialog doesn't take any parameters besides the URL to share any more; everything else (image, title, description) is taken from the Open Graph meta data the URL delivers.

Comment: i already try open graph same error show i'm test on facebook share link then show this error   An internal error occurred while linting the URL.

Comment: Then you should file a bug report. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/